# Google App Script tryLock/waitLock timeout limit cumulative for subsequent web app calls?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timeout, locking

I have been trying to debug a problem where I am writing multiple new rows (via multiple HTTP GETs) to a google spreadsheet with GAS but they seemed to fail for getting a lock after a few of them were written.  I initially had the timeout to 5000 mS (5 secs) which should have been plenty of time for a single call but what I noticed is if I had like 20 rows to add, that timeout was causing random row updates to fail.
When I moved the time to 30 sec then 20 rows worked fine.  But if I went to 60 rows, I again got random fails. Move to 60 sec timeout seemed to work there.

It seems like this timeout effectively needs to account for the cumulative time it will take to write out all rows.  The more I think about this I think this makes sense since I'm making these calls from a flutter/web project via an async method.  The dart code below for the HTTP GETs...

```
  void submitOrder(String orderParms) async {
    try {
      String fullURL = "$URL$orderParms";
      await http.get(fullURL).then((response) {
        callback(convert.jsonDecode(response.body)['status']);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

The GAS doGet method below...

```
function doGet(request){
  var prodID = "1qNt0Q-not-K37U-the-Ea8Fa-real-ynUF-url-xwskYfmDgnMEw2lX_LFblSuDw"; 
  var result = {"status": "SUCCESS"};
  try {
    // Get all Parameters
    var lastName   = request.parameter.lastName;
    var firstName  = request.parameter.firstName;
    var lock = LockService.getUserLock();  
    if (lock.tryLock(60000)) {     // currently using 60 sec to be safe??
      // Open the correct sheetGoogle Sheet using ID
      var sheet_prod = SpreadsheetApp.openById(prodID);
      var rowData    = sheet_prod.appendRow([lastName, firstName]);
      // Need to flush these updates so they fully take before releasing the lock
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      // ok, done important spreadsheet stuff, release the lock
      lock.releaseLock();
    // else did not get a lock
    } else {
      result = {"status": "FAILED - No Lock!", "message": "Lock timed out"};      
    }
  } catch(exc){
    result = {"status": "Exception! FAILED", "message": exc.message};
  }
  // Return result
  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);  
}
```

I currently have the timeout set at 60 seconds to ensure I can handle like 30-40 rows with no failures to get the lock. Is there any harm in setting the timeout this high? Any insights greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What's the error message? What line are you getting it at?

Answer (score 0):

The [official docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#waitlocktimeoutinmillis) doesn't mention any "harm" for using "large" `milliseconds` number so this depends entirely on this affecting or not the purpose of your web app and/or the purpose of your spreadsheet.

Sidenote: As your code doesn't do any change of the spreadsheet after you release the doc, it's not necessary to include `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Rubén, Google official documentation doesn't mention the max value of the lock time out. But make sure your whole runtime execution time is not exceeding the script runtime limit defined in this page https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations

Current limit is 6 min/execution